# delete and add row in view Based NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nstablecellview

I did IOS development but new to OSX. I am facing problem that I delete the row in NStableView successfully by clicking the button in row of table but when I click on add button the deleted row appears again and then its not deleted.
Here is my delete function

```
   func delIssue(_ sender:NSButton)
{
  let btn = sender
  if btn.tag >= 0
  {
    let issueValue = issueKeys[btn.tag]
    for index in 0..<issueName.count
    {
      if issueValue == issueName[index]
      {
        issueName.remove(at: index)

        rowCount = rowCount - 1
        self.tableView.removeRows(at: NSIndexSet.init(index: index) as IndexSet , withAnimation: .effectFade)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

rowCount is basically variable which I increment when row is added and decrement when row is deleted respectively.
My adding Row function is

```
    @IBAction func addRow(_ sender: Any)
  {
    rowCount += 1
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

And data source is

```
  func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
{
  return rowCount
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `issueName` and the rows? Why do you call `reloadData`?

Comment: You don't really provide any useful piece of information.

Comment: sorry guys for late reply. issueNames is basically an array on which i handle data and its used for populating the table rows. when user clicks on delete button i just remove the specific index and after removing i reload the data.

Comment: i am basically coming from IOS environment . in iOS, on deletion we just remove the particular data and reload the tableview. so i am just trying to do same thing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not assign tags to buttons in an `NSTableView`

`NSTableView` provides a very convenient way to get the current row: The method

> `func row(for view: NSView) -> Int`

---

The code in the action can be reduced to 3 lines

```
@IBAction func delIssue(_ sender: NSButton)
{
  let row = tableView.row(for: sender)
  issueName.remove(at: row)
  tableView.removeRows(at: IndexSet(integer: row), withAnimation: .effectFade)
}
```

To add a row, append a value to the data source array and then call `insertRows`

```
@IBAction func addRow(_ sender: Any)
{
    let insertionIndex = issueName.count
    issueName.append("New Name")
    tableView.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer:insertionIndex), withAnimation: .effectGap)
}
```

---

Note:

Never call `reloadData` after `insert- / removeRows`. You get rid of the animation and the insert / remove methods do update the UI. The methods `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` are useless for a single insert / move / remove operation.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found to delete row correctly and this is how i did it

```
 self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.removeRows(at: indexSet , withAnimation: .effectFade)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```